# Mapstruct is not setting to null the Map data structures

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm using mapstruct for a while and this is the second time when I faced with an interesting (I think that's a bug, but I'm not sure of it) behavior when I'm using the NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_NULL nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.

Mapping method:

```
  @BeanMapping(nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS, nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_NULL)
  public Product patch(@MappingTarget Product target, PatchProductReqDto source);
```

Bean:

```
public final class PostProductCrudReqDto {
  ...
  @ValidTranslation(optional = true)
  private Map<String, String> description;
  ...
}
```

Generated mapping code:

```
...
if ( target.getDescription() != null ) {
            Map<String, String> map1 = source.getDescription();
            if ( map1 != null ) {
                target.getDescription().clear();
                target.getDescription().putAll( map1 );
            }
        }
        else {
            Map<String, String> map1 = source.getDescription();
            if ( map1 != null ) {
                target.setDescription( new HashMap<String, String>( map1 ) );
            }
        }
...
```

As you can see if the target "description" is not null but the source one is then the target will not be modified at all.
While I'm using the **nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_NULL** strategy I'm expecting that the destination "description" should be null after calling the mapping patch method.

(I've also tried this behavior with the latest mapstruct version: 1.4.2.Final, but with the same results)

Am I wrong?

Is there any way to force the mapstruct to set the destination Map to null if the source one is null?

Thank you so much, have a nice day.

Comment: This indeed looks like a bug. Can you please create an issue?